# are class level public properties thread safe

Tags: c#, multithreading

If w3wp.exe is the process responsible to cater all the incoming requests for the web application (correct me if i am wrong), and if I have a class let's call it Customer like this

```
public class Customer  
{  
  public string FirstName{get;set;}  
  public string LastName{get;set;}
}
```

So now when this class is accessed in the code like this

```
 var customer = new Customer();
```

An instance is created in the heap and all the threads running in the w3wp.exe have access to the properties FirstName and LastName of the customer object.

So, is FirstName and LastName properties not thread safe in this case ? Is it always wise to use private properties that belongs only to a specific instance and is thread safe?

Comment: Is it possible for two threads to get hold of the same `Customer` object in your scenario? for example, from some shared state or static container?

Comment: Nope. This class sits on the business layer and it is not static or shared. 
So, if this class is instantiated as part of a request, each instantiation in run on a new thread and so the class level public property in this scenario is thread safe as it is not static or shared resource. Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: it's not necessarily a "new" thread and most likely a cached thread. This cached thread maintains an instance of your ASP.NET application (HttpApplication or "Global"). So this thread brings with it any context that might have pre-existed.

Answer (score 3):

While the compiler creates a backing field for automatic properties, it doesn't create any synchronization on it.

As for thread safety - it depends what you are doing with an object of this class in your threads. If you have a *different* object per thread, no problem.

Things are a bit different if you are accessing the *same* object (i.e. a shared resource) from many threads:

If all you are doing is *reading* a value and not *setting* it from multiple threads, there is no problem.

A problem may occur if you are *modifying* the object from multiple threads. This *will* require synchronization, something you can add in your threaded code.

Comment: I think your answer is just plain confusing. What you say at the end is correct, but just not in the context in which the OP is asking the question and I don't believe it's even relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is ok as Oded points out. But if you are worried about threading issues don't let the compiler genearate the backing field for you but write it out yourself prefixing it [volatile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). The app will pay a performance penalty for that.

If you are really worried about threading you can manually interlock them using [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.exchange%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) on assignment.

Best practice I've seen is using simple `lock` around code + `volatile` prefix for variables in my code which apperas in multithreading context. Never had a problem using this technique.

Comment: Sorry, but why you would want both `volatile` and a `lock`? Also, if you are letting emotion ("If you are really worried") guide your multi-threaded programming, then there are probably significant gaps in your understanding.

Comment: Once you protect with a lock, `volatile` is spurious. Do you not know that? If not then you have gaps. If so then I can't understand your answer. Either way there's a problem!

Answer (score -1):

You don't have the concept very clear about how the worker process works. Essentially for each thread a new instance of your class is created. So effectively, your class does not need to be thread safe and in fact is not thread safe.

Just to be clear, you understanding of private/public fields and thread safety is not at all correct (I don't believe). So in this context you should not think of them as such.

> An instance is created in the heap and
>   all the threads running in the
>   w3wp.exe have access to the properties
>   FirstName and LastName of the customer
>   object.

No, not all the threads. Each threads will get it's own instance. I'm assuming here that you've creating an instance of your customer in a page or controller? Think of it this way, each request that your application receives is a thread and because for each request a new instance of a page (or controller) is created, any objects you create in a page or controller are also specific to that thread and so for the most part you're safe. Of course if you're doing something that you've not mentioned or you're not creating instances of your customer object in a page or controller then all kinds of other questions/scenarios will need to be answered before you have your answer.

I've written a post on my blog that explains how all this works. The purpose of the post is different but I believe what you'll learn there will help you get a better grasp of how IIS and Worker process work and how they interact with your ASP.NET application.

[ASP.NET Performance-Instantiating Business Layers](http://www.matlus.com/instantiating-business-layers-asp-net-performance/)

Comment: That largely depends on whether the developer grabs the object from an existing shared source; perhaps session/cache (if in-memory), or any static container. Which is actually pretty common. This answer is exceptionally misleading in that it completely omits this possiblity.

Comment: I also see very little relationship between the question and that blog article.

Comment: @Marc in the article I talk about how IIS/Worker Process creates and caches threads and how it applies to "global" and therefore your ASP.NET applications. That part is quite relevant to the OPs confusion. I'm sure we can paint extremely complicated situations and basically answer most questions with a "depends" (as things truly do). I'm merely attempting to keep it simple because it's clear the OP is new to either programming or multi-threaded environments like IIS/ASP.NET. Microsoft tried hard to keep people oblivious of threads in ASP.NET (at least when starting out).

Comment: None of which relates to this question, sorry. But it doesn't.

Comment: I guess we'll let the OP decide :)

Comment: I really appreciate all of you for your contributions to clear my confusion with IIS worker process and multi-threads.

Comment: Nope. This class sits on the business layer and it is not static or shared. 
So, if this class is instantiated as part of a request, each instantiation in run on a new thread and so the class level public property in this scenario is thread safe as it is not static or shared resource. Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: That's is correct, provided you business layer is instantiated by your page or controller, or as I've described it in my article. Here is how you want to see this: A Request comes in (on a thread), an instance of your page (or controller) is created by ASP.NET, so the page instance or controller is in the context of this thread (and no other). If your page creates an instance of your business module, this it too is in context. If you then create an instance of your Customer in a method of your business layer, then it too is in the context and so all is good.

Comment: Unless we see some real code it's hard to be certain. But if you're programming without trying to be too smart or trying to beat the system, typically things are thread safe in ASP.NET. I hope this all makes sense?